# Transferring duplicates in column to another page using a collection

Tags: vba

I am trying to move items within a column onto another page if a duplicate with specific criteria.

My code stops at my second if statement and I can’t figure out how to search the collection with my new rows value. I feel like I almost got it but don’t know how to fix it.

```
Sub duplicates ()

Dim tasks as collection
Set tasks = new collection

Dim row, m as long 
Dim task as variant 

Row = 9
M= 3


 Do until trim(sheets(“itemreport”).range(“k” & row).value) =“”

 If trim(sheets(“itemreport”).range(“f” & row).value) = “credited”     then

  If trim(sheets(“itemreport”).range(“k” & row).value = tasks(item)      then ‘Part I am having trouble on
       Sheets(“credited”).range(“r” & m) =  trim(sheets(“itemreport”).range(“k” & row).value)
       M = m +1

       Else: tasks.add (trim(sheets(“itemreport”).range(“k” & row).value)
End if
End if

Row = row + 1

Loop
```

Comment: It's hard to imagine that you've posted compiled code here. If it had compiled, your function, property and variables would have auto-corrected to the correct case - `trim` would become `Trim`, `M = m +1` would become `m = m + 1`, etc. I'm not convinced by those inverted commas either. If you've pasted this from web code then try compiling it first. Also, use `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and it will throw some compile errors - eg (what is `item`). If you could fix that, then we can probably help with the code. I'd also look up error handling if a collection item does not exist.

Comment: Completely agree with @Ambie's suggestions..there are multiple efficient ways to achieve what may be your goal. However posting answer by modifying your code  to working condition (you are basically missing a 2nd loop for testing all the values of the collection)

Comment: @ambie you are right, it does autocorrect itself - the reason mine wasn’t is because I had typed it up on my phone while referencing my computer.  So I always get typos for stuff like that and have to continuously go back and make sure there’s four spaces on each line.  Item it what I was having problems with - which is why I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May Try

```
Sub duplicates()
Dim Tasks As Collection
Set Tasks = New Collection
Dim Rw, m As Long, i As Long
Dim Task As Variant
Dim WsSrc As Worksheet, WsTrg As Worksheet
Dim DupFound As Boolean
Set WsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("itemreport")
Set WsTrg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("credited")

Rw = 9
m = 3
With WsSrc
Do Until Trim(.Range("k" & Rw).Value) = ""
    If Trim(.Range("f" & Rw).Value) = "credited" Then
        DupFound = False
            For i = 1 To Tasks.Count
                If Trim(.Range("k" & Rw).Value) = Tasks(i) Then  'Part I am having trouble on
                WsTrg.Range("r" & m) = Trim(.Range("k" & Rw).Value)
                m = m + 1
                DupFound = True
                Exit For 
                End If
            Next i
            If DupFound = False Then
            Tasks.Add Trim(.Range("k" & Rw).Value)
            End If
     End If
Rw = Rw + 1
Loop
End With
End Sub
```